# WinSock2 client/server communication: send & receive strings

Tags: c++, string, sockets

I am having a bit of difficulty trying to code this as I do not know a lot. I have a setup for two PCs that can communicate between each other. It works and all, but it only can send single characters to each other. One PC acts like a server if the command is executed with no IP address argument, and the other, given a server IP address, acts like a client to connect to the server.

The code is all here:

```
// Quick and dirty - error checks omitted for brevity.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

using namespace std;

void chat (int socket_d)

{
    while (true)
    {
        if (_kbhit ())
        {
            char ch;
            ch = _getche();
            int n;
            n = send (socket_d, &ch, 1, 0);
            if (ch == '\r')
            {
                cout << "\n";
            }
        }

        int n;
        int count = 0;
        char byte; // Read one byte at a time - is this efficient?
        n = recv (socket_d, &byte, 1, 0);
        if (n <= 0)
        {
            if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) // A real problem - not just avoiding blocking.
            {
                cout << "Terminated " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << (char)byte;
            if ((char) byte == '\r')
                cout << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char * argv [])

{
    // Messy process with windows networking - "start" the networking API.
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int result = WSAStartup (MAKEWORD (2, 2), &wsaData);

    unsigned short port = 25565;

    // If argument is IP address - be a client and connect to it. Otherwise
    // be a server.
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        int socket_d;
        socket_d = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        // be a client.
        struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (argv[1]); // Parse the string and create the 32 bit address.
        server_addr.sin_port = htons (port); // Watch out for the endian conversion!

        connect (socket_d, (sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof (server_addr));

        u_long iMode=1;
        ioctlsocket (socket_d, FIONBIO, &iMode); // put the socket into non-blocking mode.

        chat (socket_d);

        closesocket (socket_d);
    }
    else
    {
        // be a server
        int listen_socket_d;
        int connection_socket_d;

        listen_socket_d = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // A placeholder that will be replaced with my own address.
        server_addr.sin_port = htons (port); // Watch out for the endian conversion!

        bind (listen_socket_d, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof (server_addr));

        int backlog = 5;
        listen (listen_socket_d, backlog);

        // take only the first connection.
        struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; 
        int their_addr_size = sizeof(their_addr);
        connection_socket_d = accept (listen_socket_d, (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr, &their_addr_size);

        u_long iMode=1;
        ioctlsocket (connection_socket_d, FIONBIO, &iMode); // put the socket into non-blocking mode.

        chat (connection_socket_d);
        closesocket (connection_socket_d);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to be able to send strings instead of single characters. The way I would like this to work is by increasing the byte size it sends instead of single byte currently. The way I am assuming it could work, let's say a total size of 64 bytes is sent and received at a time.

Comment: Is this below answer solved your problem ?

Comment: just working my way through what you have given me, and understanding it

Comment: is it possible you can give it a try your self as not sure with my side why it isn't working

Comment: as Blacktempel said,  If send returns 64, you're going to experience undefined behavior. rcv_buf[63] is max if you declare it char rcv_buf[64].so increase the size to 65 to hold '\0' and recv only "sizeof(rcv_buf)-1" bytes . i changed the code.give a try now.

Comment: the code is crashing honestly not sure why? so far the line causing is this because when it is remove it doesnt crash, also the code now with the change is still display random characters/symbols, http://pastebin.com/3raxit6N this is the code from recent help from you and blacktemple, of all honesty could you try it yourself and see?

Comment: It is bad to have all the code on pastebin. In a while, this question will be helpless here.

Comment: Code that forms part of a question must be posted here, in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear from this where your problem area is actually.

My solution is below. The basic idea is to allocate send and receive buffers of equal size, append characters to the send buffer on keyboard input, and transfer the buffer when it is full or the user hits the return key.

The non-blocking `send` function might not send the whole buffer at once ([see the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149.aspx)). I decided to go ahead and block here until the entire buffer was sent so I didn't have to track separate input and transmit buffers. You could improve on this, I'm sure.

The receive part just echoes whatever bytes have been received. In general, there's no way to know whether the other user was "done" sending data, so we just print what we received after the first call to `recv`.

I always `memset` the buffers to all zeros after each send and receive to prevent weird behavior from missing null terminators. It would be more optimized to simply append a null character to the end of the current string, but I get paranoid sometimes.

Here's my code:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 64


void chat (int socket_d) 
{
  char sendBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };
  char receiveBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };
  int bufferPosition = 0;
  int charsSent = 0;
  int charsReceived = 0;
  while (true)
  {
    if (_kbhit ())
    {
      sendBuffer[bufferPosition++] = _getche();

      if (sendBuffer[bufferPosition - 1] == '\r' || bufferPosition == BUFFER_SIZE - 1)
      {
        // This defeats the purpose of a non-blocking socket, I know.
        // You can do better by keeping separate buffers for sending and
        // collecting input.
        while (charsSent < bufferPosition)
        {
          charsSent += send(
            socket_d,
            &sendBuffer[charsSent], // Treats the address of a character as a string.
            bufferPosition - charsSent, // Only send the part that hasn't been sent yet.
            0);
        }

        memset(sendBuffer, 0, bufferPosition); // Paranoid.
        bufferPosition = charsSent = 0;
        cout << "\n";
      }
    }

    charsReceived = recv (socket_d, receiveBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    if (charsReceived <= 0)
    {
      if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) // A real problem - not just avoiding blocking.
      {
        cout << "Terminated " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        return;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      cout << receiveBuffer;
      if (receiveBuffer[charsReceived - 1] == '\r')
        cout << "\n";
      memset(receiveBuffer, 0, charsReceived); // Super paranoid.
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I wouldn't really consider this "good" until it supports [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), or at least `wchar_t`. ASCII lacks a lot of characters that people expect to be able to use in a real chat application.

PS - According to Visual Studio 2013, the `inet_addr` function is deprecated. I used `inet_ptons` instead. [Here's the documentation on the Winsock implementation for it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844(v=vs.85).aspx).